# How to integrate multiple components into an API

Tags: api, architecture, integration

I am working on tying together multiple components that I have developed for my undergraduate thesis, and have hit a road block. There are five components to my project:

- Sqlite Database (Considering switching to postgres to make propping it up on Amazon RDS easier)
- Python Data Scraper
- C++ Data Transformation/Computation Layer
- C++ Data Output Component
- Angular Front-End (To be developed)

Currently all of my components are duct-taped together with a bash script, with the Angular component non-existent.

**What I want to do is the following:**

- Make an AWS hosted API which does the following:

  - Make the Data Scraper / Data Transformation layer into a cron job
  - Make the Data Output component be callable by the Angular site for certain values (at the moment I only have 1 API call in mind)

**Problems:**

- Do not know how to integrate components with various languages into an API
- Do not know how (or if it is even possible) to prop up a SQlite db onto some server.

Any suggestions to simplify this would be greatly appreciated. I have had these components completed for about a month but have not been able to figure out how to tie them together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You make things very complicated :-)

You have several languages at play here, which makes things much trickier.  I would consider rewriting your C++ code in python, or making python wrappers around it:  https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html so that you can use a python framework like one of these:  http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask
or http://python-eve.org.

If you want to use RDS, you will have to switch to one of their supported databases.  If you are OK running your own database, you will already be using a server to run your code on, just use an EBS volume there (don't use ephemeral disk unless you are going to do a very robust backup/replication process).  But considering what you have built, I would really consider using something with less maintenance overhead.  If you are willing to pay for it, [Aurora](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/) just got released for public use, and removes most of the db administration overhead work.

Comment: Aurora + RDS seems very cool, but for the scale of my database (100mb MAX), I dont think it is worth the cost. This is the reason that I am using sqlite, because the db is very light and portable.


I think I came up with a solution. Flask API which directly interfaces with my Python data scraping component, and indirectly interfaces with the c++ executable. (API gets called -> start subprocess with the C++.out executable --> Listen to stdout until C++ outputs the required data --> return that data to the API caller.)

I realize this is very convoluted, and future components will be in python.